# Highly available API - is this solution a good one?

Tags: php, http, rest, curl, high-availability

I have a client that retrieves data from a RESTful API.

My requirements are that I want the APIs in a specified order. If the preferred one cannot be reached, then the next one should be used.

The reason for this is some sort of load balancing (The apis return a generated link that points to the same servers that is used further in the application).

So initially I generate my URLs of APIS in the desired order. For exampe:

1. http://first-api.example.com/method?param=value
2. http://first-api.example.com/method?param=value
3. http://first-api.example.com/method?param=value

Now I  could just loop over those urls and return the result from the first API that responds successful. However that takes too long.
The APIs may need a significant time to respond (up to several seconds). If that adds up, a timeout over the whole process may occour.

Therefore I want to wait an acceptable amount of time (where an API usually successfully responds if everything goes right).
If that time is reached I want to request the 2nd API but also wait for the first one in case it just takes longer to respond.

After some amount of time the 3rd API gets also added to the pool

I don't want to request every API right away from the beginning because every request means a significant workload which I want to avoid if possible.

Which API which ever responds first, gets the job.

So I crated a simple class that does the described above usuing curl_multi_exec.

It gets passed 2 methods. One that delivers the API  urls one at a time, one that evaluates whether the response is a success and one public method that kicks off the process and returns the first successful response.

The class including test class looks like this:

```
<?
class MultiGetProxy
{
    private $url_src = null;
    private $response_evaluator = null;
    private $total_start = null;
    private $handles = array();
    private $mh = null;
    public function setUrlSource($callback)
    {
        $this->url_src = $callback;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setResponseEvaulator($callback)
    {
        $this->response_evaluator = $callback;
        return $this;
    }
    private function addNewHandle()
    {
        echo "adding new handle ... \n";
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, call_user_func($this->url_src));
        ;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $this->handles[] = $ch;
        curl_multi_add_handle($this->mh, $this->handles[count($this->handles) - 1]);
    }
    private function getRunning()
    {
        curl_multi_exec($this->mh, $running);
        return $running;

    }
    private function getResponse()
    {
        foreach ($this->handles as &$handle) {
            if ($content = curl_multi_getcontent($handle)) {
                echo "one handle delivered content...\n";
                if (!call_user_func($this->response_evaluator, $content)) {
                    echo "evluater said it was an error...\n";
                    curl_multi_remove_handle($this->mh, $handle);
                    if (!$this->getRunning())
                        $this->addNewHandle();
                    return false;
                }
                echo "content looks fine\n";
                var_dump($content);
                return $content;

            }
        }
    }
    public function exec()
    {
        $this->total_start = microtime(true);
        $this->mh          = curl_multi_init();
        $response          = false;
        $lastadd           = 0;
        while (!$response) {
            if (microtime(true) > $lastadd + 5.0) {
                $this->addNewHandle();
                $lastadd = microtime(true);
                curl_multi_exec($this->mh, $running);
            }
            usleep(100000);
            curl_multi_exec($this->mh, $running);
            $response = $this->getResponse();
        }
        echo "do loop done here is some info:\n";
        var_dump(curl_multi_info_read($mh));
        // Handles schliessen
        foreach ($handles as &$handle) {
            curl_close($handle);
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handle);
        }
        curl_multi_close($mh);
        $total_run = microtime(true) - $total_start;
        echo "completed in: $total_run \n";
        echo "response is:\n";
        return $response;

    }
    public function getInfo()
    {
        $info               = array();
        $info["total_time"] = $this->total_run;
        $info["start"]      = $this->total_start;

    }

}


class Test
{
    function isvalid($data)
    {
        $data = json_decode($data);
        if ($data->status > 500) { // error
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function getUrl()
    {
        static $urls = array();
        if (empty($urls)) {
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.com/sleep.php?s=8&status=200&message=first';
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.com/sleep.php?s=2&status=503&message=2nd';
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.com/sleep.php?s=2&status=200&message=3rd';
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.com/sleep.php?s=21';
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.com/sleep.php?s=22';
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.com/sleep.php?s=23';
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.como/sleep.php?s=25';
            $urls[] = 'http://test.example.com/sleep.php?s=25';
        }

        $url = array_shift($urls);
        echo "returning $url \n";
        return $url;



    }
    public function test()
    {
        $mgp = new MultiGetProxy();
        $mgp->setUrlSource(array(
            $this,
            "getUrl"
        ));
        $mgp->setResponseEvaulator(array(
            $this,
            "isvalid"
        ));
        $result = $mgp->exec();
        echo $result;
    }
}


$test = new Test();
$test->test();
```

Now my actual question is more a "request for comments" because I have never really dealed with such things.

It should be deployed in a high load environment, there will be a lot of requests.

Also are the sleeping times right?

Is it likely for me to run into tcp connection probelems?

I am sorry I cannot be more specific. I just tried to find a solution to a very specific and individual problem, and this is what I came up with.

Comment: Don't try to write your own load balancing in PHP for a high-load network, use real load balancing if it's that mission-critical.

Comment: my concern is primarily the high availibility @MarkBaker. Also the load balancing is one done by choosing one API and not routing requests through a single server and then further (load balancer).

Comment: Routing requests through a single high-performance server such as nginx and using that as your load balancer means no dependencies on writing your own (potentially buggy and certainly less efficient). For resilience, you might have an additional load balancer in front. But even that is going to be better performant than a home-rolled in PHP load balancer that tries to test availability itself.

Comment: +1 Mark.  There are load balancers that are built for this very purpose.  They do "heart beat" testing and will automatically remove any dead/slow servers from the round robin pool.  HA-Proxy is our preferred weapon (it has "High Availability" in the name).  Writing the proxy at the PHP layer would be inefficient, and ultimately, unnecessary.

Comment: thanks i will look into it and see whether i can combine it with my requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

Build a facade that sits between the API and your code. The facade does the work of deciding which API to use. The facade has HTTP objects which represent the API servers. Your code just sends and receives data to the facade, and doesn't care about which server it's using.

Then work on improving performance of the facade. Test it with mock objects that return data after the kind of times that you're anticipating.

```
interface Proxy {
  function exec();
}

abstract class AbstractProxy {

  public $response;

  public function hasResponse() {
    return !empty($this->response);
  }

}

class SingleProxy extends AbstractProxy implements Proxy {

  // the real code for connecting to the API

}

class MultiProxy extends AbstractProxy implements Proxy {

  public $singleProxies = array();
  public $delayTime = 1000000;

  public function addProxy(Proxy $proxy) {
    $this->singleProxies[] = $proxy;
  }

  public function exec() {
     foreach($singleProxies as $proxy) {
        $proxy->exec();
        usleep($this->delayTime);
        if($proxy->hasResponse() {
          return $proxy;
        } else {
          $proxy->cancel();
        }
     }
  }

}

class SingleProxyStub extends AbstractProxy implements Proxy {

  public $timeToRespond = 0;

  public function exec() {
    usleep($this->timeToRespond);
    $this->response = 'response';
  }

}

class ProxyTest() {

   public function runTest() {

     $slowProxy = new SingleProxyStub;
     $slowProxy->timeToResponse = 2000000; // 2 seconds

     $fastProxy = new SingleProxyStub;
     $fastProxy->timeToResponse = 500000; // 0.5 seconds

     $MultiProxy = new MultiProxy;
     $MultiProxy->singleProxies = array($slowProxy, $fastProxy);

     $startTime = microtime(true);
     $MultiProxy->exec();
     $endTime = microtime(false);
     log($startTime, $endTime);

   }

}
```

Comment: thats what i did... the MultiGetProxy is actually the facade

Comment: Easier to show than explain. In your client code, you just need to pass an instance of `MultiProxy`. Test this through your webserver to see what happens when you load it with twice your anticipated load. That will tell you whether your design is going to work or not, far better than anybody on StackOverflow can.